# Android Keep the screen on didn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-permissions

I have used the following code to keep the screen on in android devices.Here is the code

`getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`

But it didn't work on Samsung Tab4 .Is there any alternate code for keeping the screen on in this tab? Kindly share the cod eif you know.thanks in advance.

Comment: I will check with that code ...

Comment: I did a mistake in my code. Now i corrected it and it works perfectly